# How do I filter out matching data from 2 columns from a table?

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

I have a table here with 3 columns and I need to filter out same code branches in this table.

I am able to filter it out using this query. But not the other way around.

`select item_id from tbl_transfers where from_branch = '3000' and to_branch = '3000'`

I've tried using Having and Exists syntax, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'd like to know if there are other ways to make it like this:

Here is my sample table:

```
| item_id | fr_branch | to_branch|
| ITEM01  |  1000     |    2000  | 
| ITEM02  |  2000     |    1000  |
| ITEM03  |  3000     |    3000  |
| ITEM04  |  3000     |    3000  |
| ITEM05  |  2000     |    3000  |
| ITEM06  |  3000     |    1000  |
```

```
Expected Result
| item_id | fr_branch | to_branch|
| ITEM01  |  1000     |    2000  | 
| ITEM02  |  2000     |    1000  |
| ITEM05  |  2000     |    3000  |
| ITEM06  |  3000     |    1000  |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT item_id
FROM tbl_transfers
WHERE from_branch <> '3000' OR to_branch <> '3000';
```

By the De Morgan's laws:

```
WHERE NOT (from_branch = '3000' AND to_branch = '3000')
```

becomes:

```
WHERE from_branch <> '3000' OR to_branch <> '3000'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_transfers t
WHERE t.fr_branch <> t.to_branch
```

It filter out same code branches in your table.
You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-traditional?view=sql-server-2017)